# Combined Indexed Generics can't be derived

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following two components, which each use an interface of properties to type an `onChange` method:

```
export interface BorderValues {
  borderRadius: string;
  borderWidth: number;
  border: string;
}

export type BorderArguments = keyof BorderValues;

interface BorderProps {
  onChange: <T extends BorderArguments>(arg: T, val: BorderValues[T]) => void;
}

const Border = (props: BorderProps) => {
  props.onChange('borderRadius', '10px');
  // props.onChange('borderRadius', 10);  // error
  props.onChange('borderWidth', 10);
  // props.onChange('borderWidth', '10');  // error
  return 'Border';
}
```

and

```
export interface ContainerValues {
  padding: string | number;
  opacity: string | number;
  overflow: 'hidden' | 'visible';
}

export type ContainerArguments = keyof ContainerValues;

interface ContainerProps extends ContainerValues {
  onChange: <T extends ContainerArguments>(arg: T, val: ContainerValues[T]) => void;
}

const Container = (props: ContainerProps) => {
  // props.onChange('borderRadius', '10px');  // error
  props.onChange('padding', 10);
  props.onChange('overflow', 'hidden');
  // props.onChange('overflow', 10);  // error
  return 'container';
}
```

This all works great.  Now suppose I want to combine them... I can't set `onChange` to the combined `setArgValue` function because properties are missing from each:

```
type Arguments = BorderArguments | ContainerArguments;
interface Values extends BorderValues, ContainerValues {};

interface Props {
  // This works just fine.
  getArgValue: <T extends Arguments>(arg: T) => Values[T];
  // This obviously doesn't.
  setArgValue: <T extends Arguments>(arg: T, val: Values<T>) => void;
}

const Component = (props: Props) => {

  // error: onChange can't handle ContainerArguments.
  Border({onChange: props.setArgValue});

  // error: onChange can't handle BorderArguments.
  Container({onChange: props.setArgValue});
}
```

I tried to create a derived type, like so:

```
type Test<T extends Arguments> = 
  T extends BorderArguments ? BorderValues : 
  T extends ContainerArguments ? ContainerValues : 
  never;
```

but that also doesn't work, because I can't actually index it:

```
// This is a problem: I need the argument to both derive the correct collection,
// but also index it based on the `arg` parameter
setArgValue: <T extends Arguments>(arg: T, val: Test<T>) => void;
```

Furthermore, if I change my `Test` type to return the item at the index, like so:

```
type Test<T extends Arguments> = 
  T extends BorderArguments ? BorderValues[T] : 
  T extends ContainerArguments ? ContainerValues[T] : 
  never;
```

`Test` is always equivalent to `string | number`.  *However*, the following works:

```
type Foo = Test<'overflow'>; // 'hidden' | 'visible'
```

I've created [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-t0ZFQT60oGjBxrKrQ3Jgu6wqil6vF+nqfR2oajqsmylC1uYlrWvqtLybB7LjpO1BTu685CIuXrWFKckCU6bK6Vw05qUKmqgNqtC6gGQYhmGbKYj+jG7sQaIkFK+DwAAylM6bgCmGT4EmOD6CQySpKAV5rDeRSRmhqzrPIrYMZe6GpRsvgfkWAgQXIiF5CBGXlbIxx5bQtWKJEb6JQI+ByPQCEzFV8gpdl7xFNYUw9XMCyZAV2WgAA-DiL4VYYw2VWNoE+flWU3rNDVNYtfQXhOo6xiVrSgJx1Z9Cy9ArOVEwjUBvXJZN+RYfsoD4NxtX3CiZlgPg87yOuoDcHx1BbqQHiGEmbakKQQiJM4AjYRhiTUDYLigEETATvDAgwi5pC8IwMISNuhNMAMhw-WoUiMJIsio6wIjkMwjCqNwsiw-0YYuAIAAG2G89KezcGszTWBzV3ZDd8F3Uhj0bZhuyvUcpznG9nWTJs3EUV8e40XRjCnh4NAXmwzF2oYZ3cb0KgZdsCiWXBckS9dxGRBK1gNfbjuGM7Qauzc7uokAA) with the code thus far.

Is there any way to accomplish the type I'm trying to define?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up and use indexed access instead of conditional types.  I'm also cleaning up a bunch of (in my view) superfluous stuff not related to your issue.  Given this:

```
// BORDER COMPONENT
export interface BorderValues {
  borderRadius: string;
  borderWidth: number;
  border: string;
}
export type BorderArguments = keyof BorderValues;
interface BorderProps {
  onChange: <T extends BorderArguments>(arg: T, val: BorderValues[T]) => void;
}
const Border = (props: BorderProps) => {
  props.onChange("borderRadius", "10px");
  props.onChange("borderWidth", 10);
  return "Border";
};

// CONTAINER COMPONENT
export type ContainerArguments = keyof ContainerValues;
interface ContainerValues {
  padding: string | number;
  opacity: string | number;
  overflow: "hidden" | "visible";
}
interface ContainerProps {
  onChange: <T extends ContainerArguments>(
    arg: T,
    val: ContainerValues[T]
  ) => void;
}
const Container = (props: ContainerProps) => {
  props.onChange("padding", 10);
  props.onChange("overflow", "hidden");
  return "container";
};

// TEST COMBINATION:
type Arguments = BorderArguments | ContainerArguments;
interface Values extends BorderValues, ContainerValues {}
interface Props {
  setArgValue: <T extends Arguments>(arg: T, val: Values[T]) => void;
}
```

The following code works in TypeScript 3.4 and breaks in TypeScript 3.5:

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
  Border({ onChange: props.setArgValue }); // okay TS3.4, error TS3.5
  Container({ onChange: props.setArgValue }); //okay TS3.4, error TS3.5
};
```

This is due to a [breaking change in TS3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  The way that indexed access *writes* has been [modified](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) to be more type-safe.  If I have an object `o` of type `{a: A, b: B}` and I have a key `k` of union type `"a" | "b"`, when I *read* from `o`, I will get back a value of union type `A | B`.  And in TS3.4 and below you were allowed to *write* a value of type `A | B` back.  But that's not safe because if I have a value `v` of union type `A | B`, and I write `o[k] = v`, it's quite possible that `k` is `"a"` and `v` is a `B` and I've done something bad.  The more-restrictive-but-safer way to do this is to require that to write to a union key property I need an intersection value of type `A & B`.  That's both an `A` *and* a `B`, and it's suitable to write into `o.a` and `o.b`.  This change has made writing to index keys safe.

And frustrating.  If you do something like `const v = o[k]` you expect to be able to then write `o[k] = v` without error.  But you realize that the type of `k` and the type of `v` are actually *correlated* to each other and not *independent* of each other... and the compiler, sadly, [does not realize this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You want to say that `[k, v]` is of type `["a", A] | ["b", B]` but the compiler is essentially convinced that it is of type `["a", A] | ["b", A] | ["a", B] | ["b", B]`.  And it complains.

The assignment you are doing of `props.setArgValue` to a variable of type `BorderProps["onChange"]` suffers from the same problem.

---

So, how can we handle this?  The simplest way to do this is with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), where you just tell the compiler that its warning has been noted but is not applicable:

```
const ComponentAsserted = (props: Props) => {
  Border({ onChange: props.setArgValue as BorderProps["onChange"] });
  Container({ onChange: props.setArgValue as ContainerProps["onChange"] });
};
```

That's probably my recommendation here.

---

There's a more verbose and roundabout way to deal with this, if you care.  It looks it's still allowed to [write of a value that's been read from a *generic* index](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-500913385).  So if `k` is of generic type `K extends "a" | "b"` you can do `const v = o[k]; o[k] = v;` without error.

So we can kind of address this by making your `props.setArgValue` more generic and then concrete again:

```
type Setter<T> = <K extends keyof T>(arg: K, val: T[K]) => void;

const setterForFewerProps = <T extends U, U>(
  setter: Setter<T>
): Setter<Pick<T, keyof U>> => <P extends keyof U>(arg: P, val: T[P]) =>
  setter(arg, val);
```

The `setterForFewerProps` compiles because of this generic allowance.  Note that `props.setArgValue` is a `Setter<Values>`, and something like `borderProps.onChange` is a `Setter<BorderValues>, so you want to call`setterForFewerProps(props.setArgValue)`:

```
const ComponentFixed = (props: Props) => {
  Border({
    onChange: setterForFewerProps<Values, BorderValues>(props.setArgValue)
  });
  Container({
    onChange: setterForFewerProps<Values, ContainerValues>(props.setArgValue)
  });
};
```

That compiles fine, and is possibly slightly more type safe than the assertion.  But it's so verbose that I wouldn't bother.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-SoUUz0WMJlNcrMuz7FlkLWsttYVDszHt9ovjqcpz3LrVbndrNDXkd3kJPiQfiw-nbvT3AcDIYZr93Hb3IYeB6A6Uih2iMZjA0IwZmFyPI5l+DKosymLUHmXAFoWXKluWuRUjm-KCsKooXs+EpSiQMpgPg8AAMoTGq4DKuk+CKjg+gkPqAjmislqFOKM7LKs8hRk+05MZx9Ttk0no7nIkzkNMk5sSJsiHDx241KJChfG6QkCH2nQfrIApLCJo5iRJ8h8XkWzLquG4SIY0l7u+x4fK2xAEaAdh0EU8isKA+DEQAzIiAAsjkAGImhIbkip5PkAKygEIMgJNQoDOPQ9BgiAZhJs4UiqIiPweMAHhMLw7SyOU9DAPgySkMRhVMJQpWUFIEgSMAXmkgA7AAbAAnI5WkCIlyUGKl6WZdl1C5WgBVFSVZUVVVpi1cAhZMEUTDAOA-LcCt4QALSQeisgAMScEw5ByNt9DUNtUiXtQ11CNthamOwsjnZdrAiKd918PwsgvQxsjnr8jB2h4NCOmwd5foY6lQs8rzdCobGbAovSMr+hjgVp9A6QpoCRNSoCyhw7S0AAhNYckvsjqN7SMn6QoiWM41ceME0TtAk+TxCRNK3xA4aoN9Ks6S-Rw7BCJDD6gDD74I-8HDUz+wwYwzTNZCJoDcHMEIItc0Fo8MmJ3KzOaUwrKNKyO9MIoz2nq7jWtbi+MN65bzbG-jeEOcQsrOEWcWgMd5CIiHoBoOkADS8BhzA0cAOJ4IgirIFz9EVaAxECo04yvIUowR-pE7yNa5QeSZuygBHhwnBZHnXBHjxw28dnexefxY40AV0AFpCFhwMOAuMhczPIACqhyjwuPQdxwhiZ0lHA5yQDxz1ni8YAVRTjIcJcVJPuevKMGDD5Ou+gJP2wVxg1ebvg1wYI3LzWDPtCX2YN8SLyrf8yDYOrAFJ1SAS0KPeBE0M3xNzlkjOWg4DZWxfl3WgPc+6vgRKMaShwpIKQ2KA+kaszAiQeNYT2FN7Q9mRuuN2IQ15IO7r3fukJ0HYNkmQl80ktiYztgQhSRCegkO5r4IAA)

Comment: Absolutely awesome write-up here.  I'm going to look at this in-depth on Monday and comment back with results.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I was able to fix this using a `Partial`: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAECEHkCUBEFFqgMKQLIAVIDl7YCoCwAUAKYAeADgPYBOALqAJYB29ptAZgIYDGpEOgBMOAQVoBzAK4BbUmwDOoAN4lQoAEbCO0bkKZSFALlAL6tVhIDcazdtoB1JkPoALEy1kaON4uq20IrQmZhYs1iQAviQkrOxcfALg9hi01JRKFOwsQkrJgWKSsvL0Sqp+oNQsyK7c4aQmADz4oFnyuaAA1qQAntScggW04tJyigB8ABTckib4ADSgAG7cADYm+UEjxYoA2vgAugCUoAC848vUzr7RxCS8VWaDQWegk5RpGRspnwon5ypbB90goAHRVGp1CSkSYAcgCQV0+kMsMWsIAjAAGSjkWFHXzqECgYEZcHVWr1OEInR6AwKVGgLH4wlgDhpWhA35kyGU+H2JwuVwMpkE0BEklgiEU6FU-nONwMjGYvFWFmtWjs2y0Uj0KS0FigWGbDiwm4xYhE1AEUQASVwSFQmBweCIZCodEYcQ4PH4KCq9G4rEKoxKZSBen04RC5ksoAAPqBPDJvLRRek+Ex6D1o2EJPHE14fLZqEtvatqAB3Eyw1zOEQsWH52FLJgKJgaVakU1Rc1ehK+5D+wMsDipEGtcjZDqDtjD4M7UqAipSqENUDNCdTpTdPoDGcBoPDIpjUpTGYSOaLFbrP2zw-bE8KfbHM4XJZXIRmu7EB4sJ77udaFed5fhMADDzHDJ-guco1QlblpRhPkhiROlFSxHEVTVNk6E5EEENXOFKAjSxhUxfE8NJFdeRLMtK0VWshHrFVbHFLlqJlWFaK4csKzI5kxVZDVcIqbVdX1Q1fwPEdaG7YhbhIIl8HgABlFpHXAO1RHwG0cCMEgs0oAQH1DV4MBmegmDWRpjSPENFFAAAyW9pPnR9xl8PsfQEAA1NYpFITJJ3aPJ7BMxRFnAmTwsXZRIl8WI2G9RJQEgsMKmhegRj81YAqaFo2hybden6UAYoUM9ZlAfBoNAHKAqfQ5RQUHVsv8tcN0Kjod1K8rKovaqrzWExyufWr32uHtv1-f9qBkGgRzYYCJRMNLatg54OEmDb1A4td4JarLJHq0h5lsfx7FQwwTHgzK2typDqVoK76SOM6KguoYBTcG6uTu472tlL75SFN7zrsIZfvw-6JBOoGgjxd71EiCiKiiradsqclVyh0lDvugKkfUYkSKjYk-tagGHqI0mJER8H014TNs3J6HKdhwGuOIpms3pj7KlLHjK1xsEYbhrjBc4Xi8VsFGbiAA)